# Unable to access included variable from separate PHP script

Tags: php

I'm not new to programming but I am very new to PHP. I just can't figure out why this variable is not being recognised. I have a file called utils.php in directory `utils` like this:

```
<?php
    $the_var = 'A'

    function foo($bar) {
        echo $bar;
    }
?>
```

...and another file called work.php in a parent directory of utils like this:

```
<?php
    include('utils/utils.php');
    function doIt() {
        echo $the_var; // is always empty
        foo('bar'); // no problem
    }
?>
```

Why can't the variable `$the_var` be accessed?

Comment: Because of `function scope`.

Answer (score -1):

Variable inside function is not global. If you can access to variable $the_var use

```
function doIt($the_var) {
    echo $the_var;
    foo('bar'); // no problem
}
```

or

```
function doIt() {
    echo $GLOBALS['the_var'];
    foo('bar'); // no problem
}
```

Comment: Please, do not answer what's already answered.